# Colocando e comparando dominós em ordem em C, usando lista ou não ( caso consiga sem)

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

O programa pede para verificar se tem dominós iguais ( se tem pelo menos uma possibilidade de junção de dados 12|21) e pede para mostrar uma ordem que sega a regra básica dos dóminos ( 12|24|45|53 );

Uma entrada aceita seria:

```
3 // número de dominós<br/>
1 3 //<br/>
1 5 // possibilidades<br/>
3 2 //<br/>
2 // número de dominós<br/>
3 4<br/>
2 5<br/>
0 // 0 sinaliza o fim do input ( NumDeDados = 0) <br/>
```

e uma saída aceita seria:

```
Teste 1<br/>
sim<br/> // validade() retornou 1... existe pelo menos uma combinação
51|13|32|<br/> // FuncaoMestre... coloca os dados na "ordem"
Teste 2<br/>
nao<br/> // return != 1
nao<br/>
```

O escopo básico do programa, sem as funções lógico, pois essa é a dúvida :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int NumOfDominoes = 1, Test = 1, Dominoes=1;
int E,D;
int boolean=1;

while( NumOfDominoes != 0 )
{
    scanf("%d",&NumOfDominoes);
    while( Dominoes < NumOfDominoes)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&E,&D);
        Insert( E, D); // dominó em si
        Dominoes++;
    }

}

for( Test ; Test <= NumOfDominoes ; Test++)
{
    printf("Teste %d\n",Test);

    boolean = validity();  //retorna 1 se a sequência de dominós apresenta pelo menos uma possibilidade aceita.

    if( boolean = 1) printf("sim\n");
    else {printf("nao\nnao\n");}

        masterFunction( E, D); //coloca os dominós em ordem, 01|13|35...
}
return 0;
```

}

Está faltando as funções Insert(),Validade(),funcaoMestre()

Eu não sei como inserir corretamente, se seria uma lista, uma lista duplamente encadeada, se de precisa de vetores bidimensionais, nem como validar a possibilidade de junção e muito menos como colocar em "ordem".

Já estou há uma semana nisso, qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda.

Atualizando:

O usuário user3386109 do Stack Overflow em inglês disse:

> "A solução desse problema é conhecida como 'depth-first search', que é
>   tipicamente implementada usando recursão. Escolha um dominó inicial
>   (em ambos as orientações). Que limite as escolhas e orientações para
>   o segundo dominó na cadeia. Continue adicionando dominós até haver
>   escolhas possíveis para o próximo dominó ou para todos os dominós que
>   tenham sido adicionados. Se você tentou todo dominó inicial possível
>   com todos os subsequentes dominós e sem uso de cadeia de dominós,
>   então a resposta é não."

[Minha pergunta, e essa resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058492/comparing-and-putting-in-order-dominoes-in-c-with-a-linked-list)

Comment: Ou seja, a sua dúvida é o algoritmo. Certo?

Comment: Sim, não sei para onde vai.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vc já teve o essencial da sua resposta: construa um algoritmo recursivo.

Se você optar por usar uma lista ligada, a vantagem é que a remoção de itens vai ser bastante eficiente. Assim, dá pra construir com certa facilidade o algoritmo a seguir:

1. Construa uma lista com as peças lidas. Utilize uma estrutura de dados que contenha para cada peça os valores da esquerda e da direita (usando uma `struct`, por exemplo).
2. No programa principal, faça um laço (um `for`) para iterar sobre todos os elementos dessa lista. A ideia é que você vai testar *cada um* deles pra ver se há uma solução que começe por tal peça. São na verdade dois testes por peça: um com ela começando na esquerda (ou seja, conectando pelo número da direita), e um com ela começando na direita (ou seja, conectando pelo número da esquerda).
3. Dentro desse laço, escolha a peça atual como "primeira" e um dos números dela para iniciar. Então crie *uma sublista* a partir da remoção da primeira peça escolhida para o teste. Usando uma lista ligada essa remoção é eficiente: clone a lista original e remova dela o dominó atual do laço. Essa sublista vai ser utilizada para limitar as buscas na chamada recursiva.
4. Chame uma função (de nome `solucao`, por exemplo) que irá recursivamente processar a resposta que vc quer. Passe para essa função a sublista criada (isto é, contendo apenas os próximos dominós possíveis de serem conectados), a primeira peça (já escolhida) e o número pelo qual ela vai se conectar. Essa função vai fazer internamente algo similar os passos anteriores do programa principal: ela vai percorrer a lista recebida (que já é uma sublista da sua chamada anterior!), tentando encontrar um item que se conecta ao número recebido como parâmetro. Se não encontrar é sinal de que não existe solução para esse número/conexão. Logo, ela pode devolver um retorno indicativo de falha. Se ela encontrar uma peça que se conecte, vai precisar continuar buscando nos demais itens.
5. Assim, se encontrar uma conexão, basta criar uma nova sublista (removendo da lista "original" - que, lembre-se já era uma sublista - essa próxima peça encontrada) e buscar recursivamente por outra peça que se conecte. A ideia da recursão é justamente a busca em profundidade na árvore de possibilidades de conexões. Se a busca descer e não encontrar uma solução, as chamadas empilhadas vão retornando até que vc encontre uma solução (se ela existir). Se essa nova chamada recursiva de `solucao` encontrar uma resposta, você a achou e basta combinar a peça atual, com a próxima peça encontrada para construir parte da resposta. Se não achou, não tem solução.

Obs. Vc pode fazer a função recursiva `solucao` já devolver uma string com a solução ou uma string vazia (`""`) se não tiver solução. Assim, a sua indicação de "tem solução" é devolver as strings com a peça atual concatenada com a próxima peça, e a indicação de "não tem solução" é devolver a string vazia.

Como eu não tenho tempo pra preparar um exemplo em C puro (o que também não deveria ser feito, já que provavelmente a sua pergunta seja um trabalho de escola *que você deve aprender a fazer por si só*), eu apenas preparei um exemplo em C++. Ele não serve pra você copiar e colar, obviamente, mas talvez te ajude a entender um pouco mais a proposta de algoritmo simples.

> Lembre-se que em C você vai precisar implementar algumas das coisas
>   que ai estão facilitadas pelo uso da [*Standard Library*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_library) do C++,
>   como a lista ligada (em que eu uso o `std::vector`), a clonagem e
>   remoção de elementos (em que eu uso o operador de atribuição e os
>   algoritmos `std::vector::erase` e `std::remove`), a estrutura de dados
>   do dominó (que eu usei uma `class`, que você certamente vai utilizar
>   como uma `struct`), etc.

Enfim, eis o código:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Domino
{
public:
    unsigned short e; // Número na esquerda
    unsigned short d; // Número na direita

    // Construtor padrão
    Domino()
    {
        e = 0;
        d = 0;
    }

    // Construtor com os parâmetros 
    Domino(unsigned short e, unsigned short d)
    {
        this->e = e;
        this->d = d;
    }

    // Operador de igualdade (pra permitir a comparação usada nos métodos erase/remove)
    bool operator==(const Domino &oOutro)
    {
        return this->e == oOutro.e && this->d == oOutro.d;
    }

    // Pra facilitar a geração da string da peça
    string toString(unsigned int iNaDireita)
    {
        string s;
        if (iNaDireita == e)
            s = to_string(d) + to_string(e);
        else
            s = to_string(e) + to_string(d);

        return s;
    }
};

typedef vector<Domino> Dominos;

// Função de procura recursiva por conexoes a partir de uma peça e número dados
string solucao(Dominos vPecas, Domino oPeca, unsigned short iNumero)
{
    Domino oProxima;
    unsigned short iProximo;
    bool bFound = false;

    // Procura por uma peça qualquer que encaixe na peça + número dados
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vPecas.size(); i++)
    {
        Domino oAtual = vPecas[i];
        if (oAtual.e == iNumero || oAtual.d == iNumero)
        {
            oProxima = oAtual;
            iProximo = (oAtual.e == iNumero) ? oAtual.d : oAtual.e; // !!OBSERVAÇÃO!!
            bFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Se encontrou alguma peça que se encaixa, checka a solução
    if (bFound)
    {
        // Se só existe ela e ela encaixa, pronto! Achou-se a solução!
        if (vPecas.size() == 1)
            return oPeca.toString(iNumero) + "|" + oProxima.toString(iProximo);

        // Mas se existem mais peças, continua a busca recursivamente...
        else 
        {
            Dominos vOutros = vPecas; // Clona a lista
            // Remove a próxima peça do clone, criando a sublista
            vOutros.erase(remove(vOutros.begin(), vOutros.end(), oProxima));

            // Procura recursivamente por outra, considerando agora a próxima peça como "primeira"
            // O número para a nova conexão deve ser *necessariamente* o oposto àquele que encaixou,
            // o que foi decidido anteriormente onde está marcado com o comentário "!!OBSERVAÇÃO!!"
            string s = solucao(vOutros, oProxima, iProximo);

            if (s.length() == 0)
                return ""; // Não tem solução porque há mais peças, mas elas não encaixam
            else
                return oPeca.toString(iNumero) + "|" + s; // Tem solução! Monta e devolve!
        }
    }
    else
        return ""; // Não tem solução porque não há peças que encaixam na peça recebida como parâmetro
}

int main()
{
    Dominos vPecas;
    /*vPecas.push_back(Domino(1, 3));
    vPecas.push_back(Domino(1, 5));
    vPecas.push_back(Domino(3, 2));*/

    vPecas.push_back(Domino(3, 4));
    vPecas.push_back(Domino(2, 5));
    vPecas.push_back(Domino(3, 6));
    vPecas.push_back(Domino(4, 5));

    // Tenta uma solução com cada uma das peças, posicionada à esquerda ou à direita
    string sSolucao;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vPecas.size(); i++)
    {
        Domino oPrimeira = vPecas[i];

        Dominos vOutros = vPecas; // Clona a lista
        // Remove da lista clonada a peça usada como primeira
        vOutros.erase(remove(vOutros.begin(), vOutros.end(), oPrimeira));

        // Tenta uma solução com a peça colocada à esquerda
        sSolucao = solucao(vOutros, oPrimeira, oPrimeira.d);

        // Se encontrou, ótimo!
        if (sSolucao.length() != 0)
            break;
        // Senão, tenta com a peça colocada à direita
        else
        {
            sSolucao = solucao(vOutros, oPrimeira, oPrimeira.e);
            if (sSolucao.length() != 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    // verifica se algo foi devolvido. Se não, não há solução
    if (sSolucao.length() == 0)
        sSolucao = "Solucao nao encontrada.";

    // Imprime a resposta
    cout << "Resposta do algoritmo:" << endl;
    cout << sSolucao << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Esse código produz o seguinte resultado para as peças `3 4`, `2 5`, `3 6` e `4 5` (que eu usei no lugar do seu exemplo):

```
Resposta do algoritmo:
25|54|43|36
```

Comment: Excelente resposta, muito bem detalhada! E boa descrição de como realizar uma busca completa em árvore (busca em profundidade). Mereceu o meu +1, deveria ser aceita :)

Comment: 1 ano depois eu fiz por si só kkkk. Eu não usei nenhuma estrutura auxiliar, apenas uma árvore cuja raiz é o primeiro dominó, e muitos if's e else's(único problema é isso) para restringir as comparações apenas com as folhas e recursão claro. Ficou meio que um deque. Tá funcionando bem. Fiz em C++ mesmo. Esse problema nunca tinha saído da minha cabeça. Enfim, obrigado novamente!

Answer (score 3):

Excelente resposta do Luiz Viera! Só de curiosidade e para complementar, esse problema dos dominós é um problema clássico na teoria dos Grafos! Ele é isomórfico ao problema das pontes de Königsberg generalizado para n pontes.

O problema consiste em uma cidade cheia de ilhas e pontes. O objetivo é percorrer um trajeto passando exatamente uma vez por cada ponte. Isso pode ser modelado como um grafo considerando as ilhas como os vértices e as pontes como as arestas.

Se você colocar cada vértice como um número e considerar a peça de dominó 1|5 como uma ponte ligando o vértice 1 ao 5 e o mesmo para todas as peças, verá que os dois problemas são iguais! Assim como cada peça de dominó só pode ser gasta uma vez, cada ponte só pode ser atravessada uma vez. Assim como toda peça de dominó tem que ser gasta, toda ponte tem que ser atravessada.

Euler resolveu esse problema para todos os casos e a solução é chamada caminho de Euler. Toda solução de um jogo de dominó é também um caminho de Euler. Ele descobriu que esse problema só tem solução se o grafo for conexo e não possuir mais de dois vértices com valência ímpar.

Então para saber se o problema tem solução ou não é só ver se o grafo é conexo, o que pode ser feito facilmente com uma busca lateral (BFS) e também calcular quantas vezes cada número aparece nas peças de dominó. Se mais de dois números aparecerem um número ímpar de vezes, não existe solução! Dois números podem aparecer um número ímpar vezes, pois eles podem ser colocados no início e no fim do trajeto, mas se um terceito aparecer um número ímpar de vezes ele com certeza vai ficar do lado de fora. Então se o número 1 estiver em 3 peças, o 2 em 1 peça e o 3 em 5 peças, não existe solução (1, 2 e 3 tem valência ímpar).

Uma solução bem eficiente é "cortar" todos os números que tem mais de 2 peças. Por exemplo, se tem 4 peças com o número 5 viram 2 peças com 5-1 e duas com 5-2. Todos os vértices tem que ser cortados de acordo com os caminho que voltam para o vértice (se não o grafo fica desconexo). Depois dos cortes a solução é feita com um algoritmo guloso, já que todos os números apareceram apenas 2 vezes (exceto os finais)! Os cortes podem ser realizados de uma vez com um tipo especial de busca lateral.

Não vou colocar o algoritmo aqui agora, já que iria levar muito tempo para fazê-lo. Deixei a resposta mais por curiosidade e pra dar uma direção pra quem quiser se aprofundar um pouco mais.

Comment: Muito boa resposta! Se vc colocar o algoritmo, ai eu acho que a sua merece ser aceita! :)

Comment: Acho que isso não é necessário, já que acredito que a sua resposta é mais que suficiente nesse contexto. O algoritmo que eu tentei explicar é conhecido como algoritmo de Fleury e quem estiver interessado pode pesquisar! (Com a diferença que na explicação eu "cortei" todos os vértices antes de tudo, o usual é cortar só quando estiver naquele vértice)