# Como separar uma matriz de pares em conjuntos?

Tags: java

estou precisando solucionar um problema em java e estou com dificuldades.
Tenho a matriz com os seguintes pares:

```
0 - 1
1 - 2
2 - 4
2 - 5
3 - 6
4 - 5
6 - 7
```

Gostaria de agrupar esses números da seguinte forma:
**--Se o número 'x' tem ligação com 'y' e o número 'y' tem ligação com o número 'z', então irei agrupar x, y, z , no mesmo grupo.**
O resultado Obtido seria:

```
Grupo A: 0,1,2,4,5
Grupo B: 3,6,7
Grupo C: 8
```

[image: grafo que mostra as ligações dos Elementos de 0 até 8.]
Obrigado! Aguardo resposta!!

Comment: Nesse exemplo que você passou, quem sem seria o A, o B e o C?

Comment: Que ligação é essa? Não entendi o critério. sinceramente ainda está bastante confuso.

Comment: @DiegoF mudei a explicação, conseguiu entender? qualquer coisa eu coloco um grafo explicando as ligações. Obrigado

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo  
No exemplo A,B e C poderiam ser quaisquer números, é só um exemplo que quis dizer, se o número A tem ligação com o número B e o número B tem ligação com C eles serão agrupados no mesmo grupo.

Comment: realmente esta confuso sua pergunta..  gostaria de poder ajuda-lo  mas ta difícil de interpretar sua duvida... ate agora eu não intendi  porque o "A" ficou com os números 0,1,2,4,5 e o B com os numero 3,6,7

Comment: @Tiago segue as modificações com um grafo!

Comment: @DiegoF Segue modificações com um grafo

Comment: No gráfico consigo ver a ligação. Mas como o programa pode 'ver' isso? O que na matriz diz ao programa que há essa ligação? Qual regra poderia ser aplicada?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo a entrada do programa é a matriz que coloquei na primeira linha ela sabe que o '0' está ligado no '1' na segunda linha ela sabe que o '1' está ligado no '2' e assim por diante.
Não queria utilizar uma matriz adjacencia para mostrar as ligações pq já tenho essa matriz com os pares em mãos.

Comment: Poderia ser assim. A rotina inicia e cria o grupo 1 e adiciona a grupos. Inicia o loop a partir da linha 2. Lê a linha e questiona se o primeiro ou o segundo numero está contido em algum grupo existente se sim adiciona essa linha aquele grupo. Senão cria um novo grupo e adiciona essa linha ao novo grupo criado. E volta ao inicio do loop.

Comment: Eu só não entendi o seguinte: de onde saiu o número `8` do último grupo (grupo C), se ele não existe na matriz de entrada? :) Além disso, vc já tentou alguma coisa? A sua dificuldade específica é no que? No algoritmo para processar essa matriz? Se sim, parece ser um problema bem similar a esse: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127070/colocando-e-comparando-domin%C3%B3s-em-ordem-em-c-usando-lista-ou-n%C3%A3o-caso-consiga

Comment: O nó `8` presente isoladamente no grafo é a representação de um par que foi omitido da lista. Seria o par: `8 - 8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema proposto pode ser resolvido com um algoritmo chamado [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

Pontos importantes a se considerar:

**1)** Implementar um algoritmo de busca ([BFS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_em_profundidade) ou [DFS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_em_largura)) para percorrer os nós do grafo;

**2)** Para cada nó não identificado que for encontrado, você devera atribuir um identificador de grupo para ele;

**3)** Você deverá atribuir o mesmo identificador de grupo para todos os nós adjacentes a ele, ou seja, para todos os nós que são acessíveis a partir desse nó;

**4)** Quando não existirem mais nós adjacentes passíveis de serem identificados, você começará um novo ciclo, escolhendo um outro nó não Identificado;

**5)** Note que o fato do novo nó não estar identificado implica em que ele não era acessível a partir de nosso nó anterior e, portanto, faz parte de um grupo de nós diferente;

**6)** Quando não existirem mais nós para se identificar, o número de identificadores é o mesmo número de grupos contidos no grafo.

Neste grafo de exemplo, a identificação dos grupos é feita através de cores distintas:

[image: grafo de exemplo]

Pares:

```
1) Grupo Azul:

    a) 1-2
    b) 2-3
    c) 3-4
    d) 3-5
    e) 4-5
    f) 4-7
    g) 5-6
    h) 6-7

2) Grupo Verde

    i) 16-15
    j) 15-17
    k) 17-18
    l) 15-18
    m) 19-18
    n) 19-17
    o) 16-17


3) Grupo Vermelho:

    p) 10-11
    q) 14-11
    r) 10-13
    s) 12-13
    t) 10-12
    u) 12-14
    v) 12-11

4) Grupo Amarelo

    w) 8-9
```

Esse link também me pareceu interessante: [Connected-component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: ajudou muito tua explicação vou buscar esse algoritmo era bem isso que eu estava procurando !Muito obrigado!

Comment: @RafaelPinheiro Obrigado :)